# How to draw cycloid on curve of other function (other cycloid)?

Tags: python, math, geometry, drawing

I would like to draw cycloid that is going on other cycloid but I don't know exactly how to do this. Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

from matplotlib import animation

#r = float(input('write r\n'))
#R = float(input('write R\n'))
r = 1
R  = 1
x  = []
y  = []
x2 = []
y2 = []
x3 = []
y3 = []

length=[0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'r', animated=True)
f = np.linspace(0, 10*r*math.pi, 1000)


def init():
ax.set_xlim(-r,  12*r*math.pi)
ax.set_ylim(-4*r, 4*r)
return ln,

def update2(frame):
    #parametric equations of cycloid
    x0 = r * (frame - math.sin(frame))
    y0 = r * (1 - math.cos(frame))
    x.append(x0)
    y.append(y0)

#derivative of cycloid
dx = r * (1 - math.cos(frame))
dy = r * math.sin(frame)

#center of circle
a = dy * dy + dx * dx
b = (-2 * x0 * dy) - (2 * frame * dy * dy) + (2 * y0 * dx) - (2 * frame * dx * dx)
c = (x0 * x0) + (2 * frame * x0 * dy) + (frame * frame * dy * dy) + (y0 * y0) - (2 * frame * y0 * dx) + (frame * frame * dx * dx) -1
t1 = (-b - math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
#t2 = (-b + math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)

center1x=(x0-dy*(t1-x0))*R
center1y=(y0+dx*(t1-x0))*R
#center2x=(x0-dy*(t2-x0))*R
#center2y=(y0+dx*(t2-x0))*R

#length of cycloid
length.append(math.sqrt(x0*x0 + y0*y0))
dl=sum(length)
param = dl / R

W1x = center1x + R * math.cos(-param)
W1y = center1y + R * math.sin(-param)
#W2x = center2x + R * math.cos(-param)
#W2y = center2y + R * math.sin(-param)

x2.append(W1x)
y2.append(W1y)
#x3.append(W2x)
#y3.append(W2y)

ln.set_data([x, x2], [y, y2])
return ln,


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update2, frames=f,init_func=init, blit=True, interval = 0.1, repeat = False)
plt.show()
```

In my function `update2` I created parametric equations of first cycloid and then tried to obtain co-ordinates of points of second cycloid that should go on the first one.

My idea is based on that that typical cycloid is moving on straight line, and cycloid that is moving on other curve must moving on tangent of that curve, so center of circle that's creating this cycloid is always placed on normal of curve. From parametric equations of normal I have tried to obtain center of circle that creating cycloid but I think that isn't good way.

My goal is to get something like this:

[image]

Comment: No, that isn't a good way. This is more of a math problem than a programming one. I did a very similar problem for my in-house AP Calculus exam, and it is not very easy. You need to find the parametric equations for the cycloid (you did that), then the ones for the slope at any point on the cycloid, and the length of the cycloid from a corner point to any other point. Use those to find how much the circle has rotated along the cycloid to get to a given point on the cycloid, and combine that with the slope and analytical geometry to get your desired point. I may be able to do this later today.

Comment: By the way, do you want the epi-cycloid along just one arch of the base cycloid or of the entire cycloid? if the entire cycloid, how should the cusp points be handled? I.e. what does the rolling circle do when it reaches the end of an arch? (Your example image uses a sign curve, which has no cusp points.)

Comment: i think entire cycloid could be fine however I also had a problem with find out what it should do when it reaches the end of arch so i should be happy with just one arch instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way. Calculus gives us the formulas to find the direction angles at any point on the cycloid and the arc lengths along the cycloid. Analytic Geometry tells us how to use that information to find your desired points.

By the way, a plot made by rolling a figure along another figure is called a [roulette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette_(curve)). My code is fairly simple and could be optimized, but it works now, can be used for other problems, and is broken up to make the math and algorithm easier to understand. To understand my code, use this diagram. The cycloid is the blue curve, the black circles are the rolling circle on the cycloid, point A is an "anchor point" (a point where the rim point touches the cycloid--I wanted to make this code general), and point F is the moving rim point. The two red arcs are the same length, which is what we mean by rolling the circle along the cycloid.

[image]

And here is my code. Ask if you need help with the source of the various formulas, but the direction angles and arc lengths use calculus.

```
"""Numpy-compatible routines for a standard cycloid (one caused by a
circle of radius r above the y-axis rolling along the positive x-axis
starting from the origin). 
"""
import numpy as np

def x(t, r):
    """Return the x-coordinate of a point on the cycloid with parameter t."""
    return r * (t - np.sin(t))

def y(t, r):
    """Return the y-coordinate of a point on the cycloid with parameter t."""
    return r * (1.0 - np.cos(t))

def dir_angle_norm_in(t, r):
    """Return the direction angle of the vector normal to the cycloid at
    the point with parameter t that points into the cycloid."""
    return -t / 2.0

def dir_angle_norm_out(t, r):
    """Return the direction angle of the vector normal to the cycloid at
    the point with parameter t that points out of the cycloid."""
    return np.pi - t / 2.0

def arclen(t, r):
    """Return the arc length of the cycloid between the origin and the
    point on the cycloid with parameter t."""
    return 4.0 * r * (1.0 - np.cos(t / 2.0))


# Roulette problem

def xy_roulette(t, r, T, R):
    """Return the x-y coordinates of a rim point on a circle of radius
    R  rolling on a cycloid of radius r starting at the anchor point
    with parameter T currently at the point with parameter t. (Such a 
    rolling curve on another curve is called a roulette.)
    """
    # Find the coordinates of the contact point P between circle and cycloid
    px, py = x(t, r), y(t, r)
    # Find the direction angle of PC from the contact point to circle's center
    a1 = dir_angle_norm_out(t, r)
    # Find the coordinates of the center C of the circle
    cx, cy = px + R * np.cos(a1), py + R * np.sin(a1)
    # Find cycloid's arc distance AP between anchor and current contact points
    d = arclen(t, r) - arclen(T, r)  # equals arc PF
    # Find the angle φ the circle turned while rolling from the anchor pt
    phi = d / R
    # Find the direction angle of CF from circle's center to rim point
    a2 = dir_angle_norm_in(t, r) - phi  # subtract: circle rolls clockwise
    # Find the coordinates of the final point F
    fx, fy = cx + R * np.cos(a2), cy + R * np.sin(a2)
    # Return those coordinates
    return fx, fy

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = 1
R = 0.75
T = np.pi / 3

t_array = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 201)
cycloid_x = x(t_array, r)
cycloid_y = y(t_array, r)
roulette_x, roulette_y = xy_roulette(t_array, r, T, R)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.axhline(y=0, color='k')
ax.axvline(x=0, color='k')

ax.plot(cycloid_x, cycloid_y)
ax.plot(roulette_x, roulette_y)

plt.show()
```

And here is the resulting graphic. You can pretty this up as you choose. Note that this only has the circle rolling along one arch of the cycloid. If you clarify what should happen at the cusps, this could be extended.

[image]

Or, if you want a smaller circle and a curve that ends at the cusps (here `r = 1`, `T = 0` `n = 6` (the number of little arches), and `R = 4 * r / np.pi / n`),

[image]

Comment: Nice implementation. Is the first picture made with Geogebra or another tool?

Comment: @MBo: That was made with Geogebra. Making that graphic took more time than making the code and the other graphics, but it was worth it to explain my code and also to test it.

Comment: @MBo: (I think I saw another comment from you.) The cycloid in my Geogebra Classic 5.0.476.0-d graph is not a circular arc, it is a real cycloid. I typed `R=1` into the input box to create that number then typed `(R*(t - sin(t)), R*(1 - cos(t)))`. Geogebra created a parametric curve with the expression `Curve((R (t - sin(t)), R (1 - cos(t))), t, 0, 2π)` which has the parameter limits `0` to `2π` and graphed it, which is what I wanted. I renamed it to `cyc` and colored it blue. I then copied its expression to the input line and changed the limits to `π / 3, 2π / 3` and got the cycloid arc.

Comment: @Mbo:  I then colored that arc red and made it slightly thicker. Then I made the arc's endpoints `A` and `P` by entering `cyc(pi/3)` and `cyc(2*pi/3)`. The end result was a cycloid and its arc that was real and could be used for testing. Until this project, I did not know that Geogebra could do parametric curves--I will use that often now!

Comment: Yes, I removed my comment when I found there is a way to build curves - but interactive one [like this](https://www.geogebra.org/m/j4b6exfW) - but I still don't know how to cause point at the circle to draw line (perhaps I have to read manual :)). Big thanks for useful info about simple method of curve drawing.

Comment: @MBo: That curve in the link you gave is probably done with an expression like `Curve((R (t - sin(t)), R (1 - cos(t))), t, 0, tfinal)` where the ending parameter value `tfinal` is controlled by the slider. And you are very welcome--my pleasure.

Comment: It looks great but I don't understand formulas for direction angles of the vector normal and for arc length.

Comment: @Zekhire: `dir_angle_norm_out(t, r)` takes the cycloid made with a circle of radius `r` and the point on the cycloid that has the parameter `t` and calculates the "direction angle" of a vector through the point and perpendicular to the cycloid at the point. There are two perpendicular directions, so the `out` routine takes the direction to the left, to the outside of the cycloid. At point `A` in my diagram it is the direction angle of vector `AD` and at point `P` it is vector `PC`. A "direction angle" is between the vector and a ray parallel to the positive x-axis. Is that clear?

Comment: I don't understand why dir_angle_norm_in(t, r) is computed as -t/2 and why arclen(t, r) is computed as 4.0 * r * (1.0 - np.cos(t / 2.0)). Have you determine these formulas analytically?

Comment: @Zekhire: Yes, I found them with calculus, as I stated in the first paragraph of my answer. The arc length is found in the conventional way--do you need details? The direction angle comes from the formula for the derivative--some details for finding the derivative are in Mbo's answer. The arctangent of the derivative is the direction angle of the tangent ray. Subtract pi/2 from that and you get the direction angle for the normal vector to the right--or "in" in my code. Add pi/2 to get the left ("out") direction angle. Clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate coordinates of the center of rolling circle using [parallel curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve#Parallel_curve_of_a_parametricaly_given_curve) definition. Parametric equations for this center are rather simple (if I did not make mistakes):

for big cycloid:

```
 X = R(t - sin(t))
 Y = R(1 - cos(t))
 X' = R(1 - cos(t))
 Y' = R*sin(t)
```

parallel curve (center of small circle):

```
Sqrt(X'^2+Y'^2)=R*Sqrt(1-2*cos(t)+cos^2(t)+sin^2(t)) =
                R*Sqrt(2-2*cos(t))=
                R*Sqrt(4*sin^2(t/2))=
                2*R*sin(t/2)

 x(t) = X(t) + r*R*sin(t)/(2R*sin(t/2)) =
        R(t - sin(t)) + r*2*sin(t/2)*cos(t/2) / (2*sin(t/2)) = 

        R(t - sin(t)) + r*cos(t/2)

  y(t) = Y(t) - r*R*(1-cos(t))/(2*R*sin(t/2)) =
         R(1 - cos(t)) - r*(2*sin^2(t/2)/(2*sin(t/2)) =  

         R(1 - cos(t)) - r*sin(t/2)
```

But trajectory of point on the circumference is superposition of center position and rotation around it with angular velocity that depends on length of main cycloid plus rotation of main tangent.

Added from dicussion in comments:

cycloid arc length

```
  L(t) = 4R*(1-cos(t/2))
  to use it for small circle rotation, divide by r
```

tangent rotation derivation

```
fi(t) = atan(Y'/X') = atan(sin(t)/(1-cos(t)) = 
                      atan(2*sin(t/2)*cos(t/2)/(2(sin^2(t/2))) = 
                      atan(ctg(t/2)) = Pi/2 - t/2
```

so tangent direction change is proportional to big cycloid parameter

and final result is (perhaps some signs are not correct)

```
 theta(t) = L(t)/r + t/2 + Phase
 ox(t) = x(t) + r * cos(theta(t))
 oy(t) = y(t) + r * sin(theta(t))
```

Comment: Can you tell me how you get these formulas? From what I have computed i get
x(t) = r(t - sin(t)) + R/sqrt(2) and
y(t) = r(1- cos(t)) - R*sqrt((1-cos(t)/2)
where r is radius from first cycloid and R is radius from second.
What's weird my formulas give me weird plot whereas your have slightly more sense.

Comment: I've added derivarion (R for big cycloid, r for small one)

Comment: @MBo you can integrate `Sqrt(X'^2+Y'^2)` to obtain the surface distance travelled along the big cycloid, and use it to calculate the rotation of the smaller circle (and thus the scaled parameter of the smaller cycloid).

Comment: It is quiet good but i would like to draw cycloid on the upper side and not on upper. If you look at parallel curve you can notice that it repeating periodically. I need to remove the lower part.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Yes, I can find arc length. But doubt - should I add tangent to rotation of the smaller circle? (analogy: when r/2 circle rolls about r circle, it undergoes 3 full rounds rather than 2)

Comment: @Zekhire there are two parallel curves for two normal directions

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I don't catch why such expression. Quick calculation gives arc length `4R*(1-cos(t/2))`  (similar to your deleted  (why?) answer) and tangent rotation - very simple `t/2`

Comment: @MBo yeah you're right (I didn't take the tangent rotation into account)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. Somehow I have managed to accomplish that. Solution is maybe ugly but sufficient for me.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

from matplotlib import animation

r = float(input('write r\n'))
R = float(input('write R\n'))
#r=1
#R=0.1
x  = []
y  = []
x2 = []
y2 = []

x_1=0
x_2=0


lengthX=[0]
lengthY=[0]
lengthabs=[0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'r', animated=True)
f = np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 1000)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-r,  4*r*math.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 4*r)
    return ln,

def update2(frame):
    #cycloid's equations
    x0 = r * (frame - math.sin(frame))
    y0 = r * (1 - math.cos(frame))
    x.append(r * (frame - math.sin(frame)))
    y.append(r * (1 - math.cos(frame)))

    #arc's length
    lengthabs.append(math.sqrt((x0-lengthX[-1])*(x0-lengthX[-1])+(y0-lengthY[-1])*(y0-lengthY[-1])))
    lengthX.append(x0)
    lengthY.append(y0)
    dl=sum(lengthabs)
    param = dl / R

    #center of circle
    center1x = r * (frame - math.sin(frame)) + R * math.cos((frame+2*math.pi) / 2)
    center1y = r * (1     - math.cos(frame)) - R * math.sin((frame+2*math.pi) / 2)

    if(frame<2*math.pi):
        W1x = center1x + R * math.cos(-param)
        W1y = center1y + R * math.sin(-param)
    else:
        W1x = center1x + R * math.cos(param)
        W1y = center1y + R * math.sin(param)

    x2.append(W1x)
    y2.append(W1y)
    ln.set_data([x,x2], [y,y2])
    return ln,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update2, frames=f,init_func=init, blit=True, interval = 0.1, repeat = False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why do you calculate arc length numerically when simple closed-form expression does exist? Also you omit tangent rotation.

Comment: I haven't looked at your code in detail, your code shows different results from mine--it looks different and has a different number of arches. I tested my code fairly well with Geogebra, so I am pretty confident that it is correct. That means your code is probably incorrect. I'll try to look closely at your code in the next couple of days to find the error.

Comment: I now see that MBo's analysis of your code is correct. Your calculation of the final point's coordinates, `W1x` and `W1y`, is off because you do not take the "tilt" of the little circle (the direction of vector CP in my diagram) into account. Thus your resulting curve is incorrect.

Comment: I believe that you are right but I hadn't much time left after writing my code so I couldn't wait for you to share your code. Afterall my solution (however not correct) was sufficient for my purposes. I thank you for your help and later I will look at your code and analyze it properly.